# php inventory and order management system

Tags: php, mysql

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['order_item']); $i++) 
{   

$order_date=$_POST['order_date'];
$customer_name=$_POST['customer_name'];
$salesman_name=$_POST['salesman_name'];
$area_code=$_POST['area_code'];
$product_name=$_POST['product_name'][$i];
$item_qty=$_POST['item_qty'][$i];//product actual quality
$order_item=$_POST['order_item'][$i]; //order item number 
$billed_qty=$_POST['itqty'][$i]; // product billed quantity editable
$prod_mrps=$_POST['mrps'][$i];
$prices=$_POST['price'][$i];
$discount=$_POST['qty'][$i];
$amount=$_POST['total'][$i];    
$prod_qty = $_POST['prod_qty'][$i];//available quantity
$batch_no = $_POST['batch_no'][$i];//batch number
$qtyout = 0;
$result = $dbo->query("SELECT `batch_no`, `prod_id`, `prod_name`, `total_qty` FROM `sm_product_batch` where `prod_name` = '$product_name' and `batch_status` = 'Active_batch' order by batch_no asc");
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            if($billed_qty > 0)
            {
                $batchout = 0;
                $rem = max($row['total_qty']-$billed_qty,0);
                if($rem == 0)
                    $batchout = $row['total_qty']; //This means there are no items of this cost remaining
                else
                    $batchout = $billed_qty; //This means there are items remaining and therefore our next loop (within the while) will check for the next expensive item

                $billed_qty -= $batchout;
                $qtyout += $batchout;
                $sql = "Update sm_product_batch set total_qty = (total_qty - $batchout) where prod_name='".$product_name."' AND batch_no = ".$row["batch_no"];
                $dbo->query($sql);
                $sql1 = "Update sm_product_batch SET batch_status=CASE WHEN total_qty='0' THEN 'Inactive_batch' ELSE 'Active_batch' END where prod_name='".$product_name."'";
                $dbo->query($sql1);
            }
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sm_invoice (order_id,invoice_id,product_name,customer_name,salesman_name,order_item,area_code,order_date,invoice_date,item_qty,billed_qty,batch_no,prod_mrp,price,spl_dis,total) VALUES ('".$order_id."','".$order_id."','".$product_name."','".$customer_name."','".$salesman_name."','".$order_item."','".$area_code."','".$order_date."','".$invoice_date."','".$item_qty."','".$_POST['itqty'][$i]."','".$batch_no."','".$prod_mrps."','".$prices."','".$discount."','".$amount."')";
        $dbo->query($sql);
}
```

> This is my code to update inventory with batch and invoice table. This code is only working for my first product. Need this to be done for all products of an order.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should really switch to prepared statements.

Comment: Try echo'ing out `$billed_qty' on each loop, see if this is being adjusted as you think.

Comment: You need to debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['order_item']); $i++) 
{   
$order_date=$_POST['order_date'];
$customer_name=$_POST['customer_name'];
$salesman_name=$_POST['salesman_name'];
$area_code=$_POST['area_code'];
$product_name=$_POST['product_name'][$i];
$item_qty=$_POST['item_qty'][$i];//product actual quality
$order_item=$_POST['order_item'][$i]; //order item number 
$billed_qty=$_POST['itqty'][$i]; // product billed quantity editable
$prod_mrps=$_POST['mrps'][$i];
$prices=$_POST['price'][$i];
$discount=$_POST['qty'][$i];
$amount=$_POST['total'][$i];    
$prod_qty = $_POST['prod_qty'][$i];//available quantity
$batch_no = $_POST['batch_no'][$i];//batch number
$qtyout = 0;
$result = $dbo->query("SELECT `batch_no`, `prod_id`, `prod_name`, `total_qty` FROM `sm_product_batch` where `prod_name` = '$product_name' and `batch_status` = 'Active_batch' order by batch_no asc");
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            if($billed_qty > 0)
            {
                $batchout = 0;
                $rem = max($row['total_qty']-$billed_qty,0);
                if($rem == 0)
                    $batchout = $row['total_qty']; //This means there are no items of this cost remaining
                else
                    $batchout = $billed_qty; //This means there are items remaining and therefore our next loop (within the while) will check for the next expensive item
                $billed_qty -= $batchout;
                $qtyout += $batchout;
                $sql = "Update sm_product_batch set total_qty = (total_qty - $batchout) where prod_name='".$product_name."' AND batch_no = ".$row["batch_no"];
                $dbo->query($sql);
                $sql1 = "Update sm_product_batch SET batch_status=CASE WHEN total_qty='0' THEN 'Inactive_batch' ELSE 'Active_batch' END where prod_name='".$product_name."'";
                $dbo->query($sql1);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sm_invoice (order_id,invoice_id,product_name,customer_name,salesman_name,order_item,area_code,order_date,invoice_date,item_qty,billed_qty,batch_no,prod_mrp,price,spl_dis,total) VALUES ('".$order_id."','".$order_id."','".$_POST['product_name'][$i]."','".$customer_name."','".$salesman_name."','".$_POST['order_item'][$i]."','".$area_code."','".$order_date."','".$invoice_date."','".$item_qty."','".$batchout."','".$row["batch_no"]."','".$_POST['mrps'][$i]."','".$_POST['price'][$i]."','".$_POST['qty'][$i]."','".$_POST['total'][$i]."')";
        $dbo->query($sql);
            }
        }
}
```

> Found the answer after lot of debugging. 
>   Thanks for all your response.